# ¿Como guardar la fecha de un calendar en vb.net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

**Necesito insertar y darle un update a la fecha directa del calendar**

[image: imagen del proyecto]

```
comando.CommandText = ("UPDATE dictamen SET fecha='" & fecha.Text & "',nombre ='" & nombre.Text & "',cargo ='" & cargo.Text & "',area ='" & area.Text & "',equipo ='" & equipo.Text & "',num_inv ='" & num_inv.Text & "',dictamen ='" & dictamen.Text & "',recomendacion ='" & recomendacion.Text & "' WHERE ID = " & Label2.Text & "")

comando.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO dictamen(fecha,nombre,cargo,area,equipo,num_inv,dictamen,recomendacion) VALUES ('" & fecha.Text & "','" & nombre.Text & "','" & cargo.Text & "', '" & area.Text & "','" & equipo.Text & "','" & num_inv.Text & "','" & dictamen.Text & "','" & recomendacion.Text & "')")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es bastante sencillo, solo tienes que formatear la fecha de la siguiente manera:

```
Cdate(txtfecha.text).tostring("yyyyMMdd")
```

El dato fecha lo deberá de guardar de la manera que lo abajo con un `cdate()` que convierte un objeto a fecha y el `.tostring(formato de fecha)`.

Pruébalo de esta forma;

```
comando.CommandText = ("UPDATE dictamen SET fecha='" & cdate(fecha.Text).tostring("yyyyMMdd") & "',nombre ='" & nombre.Text & "',cargo ='" & cargo.Text & "',area ='" & area.Text & "',equipo ='" & equipo.Text & "',num_inv ='" & num_inv.Text & "',dictamen ='" & dictamen.Text & "',recomendacion ='" & recomendacion.Text & "' WHERE ID = " & Label2.Text & "") 
comando.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO dictamen(fecha,nombre,cargo,area,equipo,num_inv,dictamen,recomendacion) VALUES ('" & cdate(fecha.Tex).tostring("yyyyMMdd") & "','" & nombre.Text & "','" & cargo.Text & "', '" & area.Text & "','" & equipo.Text & "','" & num_inv.Text & "','" & dictamen.Text & "','" & recomendacion.Text & "')")
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro, en lugar de crear múltiples respuestas, edita la que ya existe para añadir más información. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás una medalla).

Comment: Funciono para el el Insert, pero para el update no funciona, guarda una fecha no valida ( 01/01/1900)

Comment: Probablemente es lo que retorna el control,pero el formateo es correcto, depura el proyecto y revisa que retorna el calendar.

Comment: Estas en todo lo correcto, fue culpa mia  por no checar el codigo , funciono perfecto muchisimas gracias

Comment: Un gusto ser de ayuda estimado.